# Verifying a random subset of a parallel repitition of sigma protocols

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, soundness, sigma-protocol

Suppose a prover computes a non-interactive proof which is composed of $k$ parallel repetitions of a sigma protocol with binary challenges (and knowledge error $\frac{1}{2}$), composed in parallel and transformed into a non-interactive proof by Fiat-Shamir.

The verifier samples a random subset of $m$-out-of-$k$ of the repetitions and verifies them. They accept if the chosen subset of repetitions are accepted.

A forger does not know which repetitions are verified, only that they are chosen uniformly at random.

Are there any works that discuss the soundness implications of only verifying a random subset of parallel repetitions? This is particularly of interest since a verifier may save in the verification costs by only verifying part of the proof.

Some thoughts:
A malicious prover who wishes to mount an attack may compute $k-1$ of the commitment phases (as is done in the ZK simulator), and enumerating the last one until they yield a good hash that satisfies $m$ challenge bits. This can be achieved for small $m$ efficiently but succeeds with very low likelihood. There is also some kind of computational trade-off here for choosing a sufficient number of challenge bits that are 'good' in the sense that the verification succeeds for the corresponding repetitions, and the probability that the verifier selects a subset from the repetitions that are only 'good'.

Comment: It would certainly still be sound, but it's unclear that there would be any advantage compared to just sending $m$ proofs. If you want the verifier to put in less work than the prover, you should look into [succinct proofs](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-031-15802-5_18).

Comment: I'm well aware of succinct proofs. I think it is definitely better than sending $m$ proofs, but for small $m$ I still think it is not secure, which is why I am asking about it.